# jquery content panel switcher show button as active on load

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using this content panel switcher from https://code.google.com/p/jquery-content-panel-switcher/ and using code from a previous post on here I managed to get it to show each item as active when clicked.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/n4pPy/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  jcps.fader(300, '#switcher-panel');
  $('.nav_buttons a').click(function(event){
    $('.nav_buttons a').css({ 'background-color' : '' });
    $(this).css({ 'background-color' : 'red' });
  });
});
```

How can I get it to show 'home' as active on page load?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this Jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
jcps.fader(300, '#switcher-panel');

    $('.nav_buttons a').click(function(event){
      $('.nav_buttons a').css({ 'background-color' : '' });
      $(this).css({ 'background-color' : 'red' });
    });
     //add this css
 $('#home').css({ 'background-color' : 'red' });
});
```

<kbd>**[RESULT](http://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/n4pPy/23/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I suggest you get yourself another tab switching plugin for jQuery. There are plenty. This one seems to be painfully outdated. It does not have any events and does not attach any class names that may be used to identify (and style) active content.

Having said that, you can apply the same styling to the first element on init as when you click it.

We'll use the `.filter(':first')` selector for that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  jcps.fader(300, '#switcher-panel');

    $('.nav_buttons a').click(function(event){
        $('.nav_buttons a').css({ 'background-color' : '' });
        $(this).css({ 'background-color' : 'red' });
    }).filter(':first').css({ 'background-color' : 'red' });

});
```

Here's the updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/n4pPy/24/

Comment: I'll have a look at other versions too when I get chance, thanks for the advice.